# Want to access dynamic property name from dynamic object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, object

I have following JSON format.

```
{
   "data": [
     {
        "id": 1,
        "variants": [
            {
               "name": "Test",
               "images": {
                    "WHITE": [
                         {
                           "id": 13,
                           "name": "Testname"
                         }
                      ]
                 } 
            }
           ] 
     }
     ]
}
```

Now I am Desalinizing it using following method :

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
```

And then in items I am getting variants.

**I am using dynamic because in this images node in some record it is coming as empty array and in some it is coming as JSON object so..**

I have following dynamic object. If I write down following console line then below output will come.

```
Console.WriteLine(variant.images)
```

It's output is looking like this below :

```
{
   "WHITE": [ // I want to get this WHITE in one variable, this color name.
       {
          "id": 13,
          "name": "Testname"
       }
    ]
}
```

Now this WHITE will come dynamic in few records it can come BLACK and in few it can come RED..

So based on that color value I need to put further logic. So how can I access that value only.

I want to save that color name value in one variable and then want to use it.

Thanks

Comment: How did you create and populate the `variant` variable? What is the data type of `images`? This looks like JSON, can you parse it using a JSON parsing library?

Comment: @gunr2171 I have added more details in question

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid deserializing into `dynamic`, rather use `JObject.Parse()`.

If you know what color name to search for:

```
var input = "{\"data\":[{\"id\":1,\"variants\":[{\"name\":\"Test\",\"images\":{\"WHITE\":[{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"Testname\"}]}}]}]}";
var json = JObject.Parse(input);
var colorToSearchFor = "WHITE";
var colorElement = json.SelectToken($"$.data[0].variants[0].images.{colorToSearchFor}[0]", true)!;

Console.WriteLine(colorElement["id"]!.Value<int>());
Console.WriteLine(colorElement["name"]!.Value<string>());

// prints "13" and "Testname"
```

If you don't know what the color name is, but know where it *should* be:

```
var input = "{\"data\":[{\"id\":1,\"variants\":[{\"name\":\"Test\",\"images\":{\"WHITE\":[{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"Testname\"}]}}]}]}";
var json = JObject.Parse(input);
var imagesElement = json.SelectToken($"$.data[0].variants[0].images", true) as JObject;

foreach (var possibleColorElement in imagesElement.Properties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(possibleColorElement.Name);
}

// Prints "WHITE"
```

My token selectors us a lot of `[0]`'s, so adapt those if the object you are looking for isn't the first object in the arrays. `[*]` might work, but use with care.

Answer (score 0):

I have showed you several times already how to use LINQ

```
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
    
    List<string> imageColors = jObj["data"]
                      .SelectMany(x => ((JArray)x["variants"])
                      .SelectMany(x => ((JObject)x["images"])
                      .Properties().Select(x => x.Name)))
                      .ToList(); // or FirstOrDefault if you want one colour

    string firstImageColor = imageColors[0]; // "WHITE"
```

Comment: I am getting this error : `unable to cast object of type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.`

Comment: @SamiIn  Check a json string , it should be the same as you published.

Comment: yes it is same as I have posted

Comment: @SamiIn Sorry, but all my code is tested. I think you have this error from somewhere else.